# How to prevent loading PrimeFaces theme.css in h:head

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces as main JSF component library. But I need it only on one web page. The other web pages do not use PrimeFaces library. I am using template, here is a part of template that matters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">  
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <title>
            <ui:insert name="titleOfPage">Insert title</ui:insert>
        </title>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="basic.css" library="css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="template.css" library="css" />
    <f:facet name="last">
        <ui:insert name="scriptOfPage" />
        <h:outputScript name="mainScript.js" library="javascript" />
        <ui:insert name="styleOfPage" />
    </f:facet>
</h:head>   
<h:body>
```

I found out that with h:head defined, it automatically loads PrimeFaces theme.css. The part of the source of the loaded page looks like this:

```
<link href="/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I am not using any of primefaces in template or in page, that implements template. But the h:head stil loads the theme.cs. Is it possible to load this theme only when required?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could prevent loading the theme in web.xml:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And on the site you want to have the theme just add the css:

```
<link href="/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Maybe you also know how to prevent loading Primefaces JQuery?

Comment: As much as I know - neither primefaces.js, primefaces.css nor jquery.js will be loaded if you don't use it on your page. Just tried it with primefaces 3.4 and a simple page and it was like that.

Comment: Yeah I am using 3.3.1, just noticed that they released 3.4. Will try that, but as I understand, when you use h:head, it will load resources for your custom JSF library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe override headrenderer?
I would just remove the part that encodes it and then do it manually on the one page.

I can think of many other ways to do it that way, let me know if you need more concrete help.

I think you can use this http://code.google.com/p/primefaces-extensions/source/browse/primefaces-extensions/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/head/HeadRenderer.java?r=1353